# Lightning DataTable - AutoSave DraftValues

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

```
<aura:component >
    <!-- attributes -->
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="errors" type="Object" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="draftValues" type="Object" default="[]"/>

    <!-- Imports -->

    <!-- handlers-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.init }"/>

    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <h1 class="slds-text-heading_large">Inline edit playground</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- the container element determine the height of the datatable -->
    <div style="height: 300px">
        <lightning:datatable
            columns="{! v.columns }"
            data="{! v.data }"
            keyField="id"
            errors="{! v.errors }"
            draftValues="{! v.draftValues }"
            onsave="{! c.handleSaveEdition }"
            onrowselection="{!c.getSelectedAccName}"
        />
    </div>
</aura:component>

({
    init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    cmp.set('v.columns', [
                {label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'accountName', type: 'text', editable: true},
                {label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'industry', type: 'text', editable: true},
                {label: 'Account Number', fieldName: 'accountNumber', type: 'text', editable: true}
            ]);
        cmp.set('v.data', [{
                id: 'a',
                accountName: 'Edge Communications',
                industry: 'Education',
                accountNumber: 'CD451796'
            },
            {
                id: 'b',
                accountName: 'GenePoint',
                industry: 'Electronics',
                accountNumber: 'CC978213'
            }]);
    },

    getSelectedAccName: function (cmp, event) {
        var selectedAccRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedAccRows.length; i++){
            console.log(selectedAccRows[i].accountName+" is selected");
        }
    },

    handleSaveEdition: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var draftValues = event.getParam('draftValues');
        helper.saveEdition(cmp, draftValues);
    },
})

({
    saveEdition: function (cmp, draftValues) 
    {
        // draft values
        var draftData = draftValues;
        console.log(draftData);

        // original values
        var originalData = cmp.get("v.data");
        console.log(originalData);

        // Question - how to save draftData in originalData
    },
})
```

Comment: Hi there, I have formatted the code here for you, but please take a moment to go through [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [take a tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) so that you can get to know the format of SFSE better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand from the title of your question, you are trying to *auto save* the `draftValues` on a `lightning:datatable`. You **cannot** *auto save* `draftValues`, you will need to write a server side logic to do so. Excerpt from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) (emphasis mine):

> The `draftValues` data structure is an array of objects. Each object describes the changed values by specifying the keyField to identify the row containing the changed values, the data column name, and the changed value for that column. **The data structure is useful to make a server side call that persists the changes in the datatable**.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I will close the ticket.